# AutoMapper not mapping composite object

Tags: automapper

I am using AutoMapper 6.2.2 to map a composite object (made up of two objects) into one, and it isn't working.

#### Source/destination types

Source type: a composite object (using suggestion from https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/389)

```
public class JoinedJob 
{
    public JobInfo job { get; set; }
    public LocationInfo loc { get; set; }
}
```

Destination type:

```
public class JobDetailsModel
{
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public string JobType { get; set; }
}
```

For testing purposes, I am using this very simple destination class, ignoring the source loc fields completely for now.

#### Mapping configuration

```
CreateMap<JoinedJob, JobDetailsModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.JobID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.job.JobID))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.JobType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.job.JTName));
```

#### Expected behavior

I expect the JoinedJob object to get properly mapped to the JobDetailsModel object.

#### Actual behavior

This doesn't work at all when using ProjectTo<>. The objects I got back had null and zero values.

#### Steps to reproduce

So I tested a single instance:

```
var testDetail = _mapper.Map<JoinedJob, JobDetailsModel>(testJob);
```

and this exception is thrown:

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type.    
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters.
JoinedJob -> JobDetailsModel (Destination member list)

NDSWebAPI.Modules.Core.BusinessLogic.JobRetrieval+JoinedJob -> NDSWebAPI.Models.Core.JobDetailsModel (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
    JobID
    JobType
```

It's as if AutoMapper doesn't recognize the `.ForMember` mappings I defined?

Should this work? I have no problems at all with mapping single objects (e.g. mapping `JobInfo` to `JobDetailsModel` works). The problem is introduced with the composite object.

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.